# How can I run multiple instances of a for loop in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, parallel-processing

I have a function which returns the usage of a CPU core with the help of a library called cpu-stat:

```js
const cpuStat = require('cpu-stat')
var coreCount = cpuStat.totalCores()
var memArr = []

function getCoreUsage(i) {
    return new Promise(async(resolve) => {
        if (i === 0) {
            cpuStat.usagePercent({coreIndex: i,sampleMs: 1000,},
            async function(err, percent, seconds) {
                if (err) {resolve(console.log(err))}
                x = await percent
                resolve("Core0: " + x.toFixed(2) + "%");
            });
        } else {
            cpuStat.usagePercent({coreIndex: i,sampleMs: 1000,},
                async function(err, percent, seconds) {
                    if (err) {resolve(console.log(err))}
                    x = await percent
                    resolve(x);
            });
        }
    })
}
```

This function is called whenever a client requests a specific route:

```js
function singleCore() {
    return new Promise(async(resolve) => {
        for (i=0; i <= coreCount; i++) {
            if (i < coreCount) {core = await getCoreUsage(i), memArr.push(core)}
            else if (i === coreCount) {resolve(memArr), memArr = []}
        }
    })
}
```

Now, this works just fine on machines which have less than 8 cores. The problem I am running into is that if I (hypothetically) use a high core count CPU like a Xeon or a Threadripper, the time it takes to get the usage will be close to a minute or so because they can have 56 or 64 cores respectively. To solve this, I thought of executing the for loop for each core on different threads such that the time comes down to one or two seconds (high core count CPUS have a lot of threads as well, so this probably won't be a problem).
But, I can't figure out how to do this. I looked into the child_process documentation and  I think this can probably be done. Please correct me if I am wrong. Also, please suggest a better way if you know one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usagePercent function  works by

1. looking at the cycle-count values in `os.cpus[index]` in the object returned by the os package.
2. delaying the chosen time, probably with setTimeout.
3. looking at the cycle counts again and computing the difference.

You'll get reasonably valid results if you use much shorter time intervals than one second.

Or you can rework the code in the package to do the computation for all cores in step 3 and return an array rather than just one number.

Or you can use Promise.all() to run these tests concurrently.